Multinomial mixed models: glmmTMB vs. mblogit. Why does glmmTMB works and mblogit gives the 'a' is computationally singular error?
Currently, I am trying to run a multinominal mixed model with one random factor in order to analyze a dataset comprising the following variables:

Demographic group: a factor with 7 groups, the response variable
Period within the season: a factor comprising 6 groups, each representing a two-week period within the season
Tracking method: a factor comprising 3 groups
season: the random factor

I want to investigate the effects of period and tracking method on the distribution of different demographic groups. I got a dataset of different seasons, so in order to take the differences between season into account, I use season as a random factor.
**What I did **
1.) running the model using the mblogit function
My code looks like the following:
mblogit_model <-  mblogit( formula = group ~ period + method ,  
                                   random = ~ 1|season , 
                                   data = modeldata,
                                   maxit=1000)

However, when running this model I get the following error: "Error in .solve.checkCond(a, tol) : 'a' is computationally singular, rcond(a)=8.45101e-17". So far I understand the error, correlated variables can cause this?
2.) Running the model using the glmmTMB function
In addition I explored other approaches and I tried the glmmTMB function. Here, I don't encouter any problems/errors. However Anova reveals here that period is not significant for the model
My code looks like the following



glmmTMB_model <- glmmTMB(group~  period + method + (1 | season), 
                                family = "binomial", 
                                data = modeldata)

My main question is: which function is the best? Since glmmTMB doesn't give any error I would prefer continuing this approach altough I don't feel sure about it. Certainly taking the errors occuring using the mblogit function.
I tried to run mblogit with each variable (period or method) separately, surprisingly I don't get an error when using only period in the model but using method as explanatory variable gives the same troubles (singular error)...
